# Inserting into database from input by clicking a button

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have done the entire coding but data isnot getting inserted in the database

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection connection = 
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/userinfo?user=root&password=admin");
       Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;
        resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from item") ;
```

Now this is the part where i have done the connection and i think it is okay because in first part where i display values from database it is working

Now that i have done this in the next part i have taken input values from input boxes

```
   <input type="submit" value="RECEIVE"  style="width:100px; height:40px" 
     name="receive ">
```

now <%

```
   PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    if(request.getParameter("receive")!=null)
    {
    String dob=request.getParameter("datepicker");
    String supplier=request.getParameter("supplier");
    String type=request.getParameter("type");
    String quantity=request.getParameter("quantity");
    String queryString = "INSERT INTO stock_quantity values(?,?,?,?)";
      pst  = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
      pst.setString(2,dob);      
      pst.setString(3,supplier);
      pst.setString(4,type);
       pst.setString(5,quantity);
      int i = pst.executeUpdate();
      if(i!=0){
       %>
      <script language="javascript">
            alert("Send sucess");
      </script>
      <%    
   }
   else{
      %>
      <script language="javascript">
            alert("Enter all data");
      </script>
      <%    
   }
 }
 %>
```

The data doesnt gets inserted.. Find the problem in the code

Comment: Java is not javascript

Comment: Do not use jdbc directly in jsp. Learn about 3tier architecture

Comment: what should i do?... I want to insert data when i click the receive button... Iif i redirect it to another page then i have to again connect database which can create a problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't make connection with db in first controller(in your case in jsp), just send your data to another controller, and there you can insert it to db. You can use either @Requestparam("param") to get single parameters, or @ModelAttribute("name") to get entire POJO object(where you will have your all parameteres).

So your html file would look like (in thymeleaf) you need to change some of thymeleaf things to jsp:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${yourObject}" method="post">
                        <div>
                            <label for="quantity">quantity:</label>
                            <input type="quantity" th:field="*{quantity}">
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

And your second controller:

```
@PostMapping("save")
    public String reset(@ModelAttribute(value = "yourObject") YourPOJOClass request) {
    //save to DB
    }
```

If you want to accept parameters, not entire object, add name parameter to jsp/html
for example:

```
                        <div>
                            <label for="quantity">quantity:</label>
                            <input type="quantity" th:field="*{quantity}" name="quantity">
                        </div>
```

And in controller you can get this parameter like that:

```
@PostMapping("save")
    public String reset(@RequestParam("quantity") String quantity)
```

Comment: i did nt create a form.. I want to do this without creating a form

Comment: That was just an example, if you want to have single button, which send request just use that:
    <form action = "" method = "post">
        <input type="submit" name="receive" value="RECEIVE" />
    </form>

Comment: can i write that form action part in submit buttoon action??

Comment: I doubt it...but why you don't try? It would take you less time, than asking here...:P 
What's wrong with button inside form ?

Comment: <form action = "" method = "post"> <input type="submit" name="receive" value="RECEIVE" /> </form>                       I used this and now its working but data inserted to the database shows null,null,...... That means i have a problem in  accepting or inserting?

Comment: Propably Inserting. You can check if you send this parameter correctly, just by printing it to the console :) 
In your controller where you accept the request:
System.out.println("quantitiy: " + quantity);

Comment: I have checked it with a alert statement. Its same. Not taking any value...